# Magento2 : Getting error while updating the data using API

Tags: magento2, customer, api, rest-api, curl

I am getting the following error while updating the record using the Magento 2 REST API.

> Error:
>
> (
>           [message] => Request does not match any route.
>           [trace] => 
>       )

I am explaining my code below.

```
$customerData = [
        'customer' => [
            "id" => 25,
            "email" => "subhra@email.com",
            "firstname" => "subhrajy",
            "lastname" => "pradhan",
            "storeId" => 1,
            "websiteId" => 1,
             "customAttributes" => [
        ],

        "addresses" => [

        ]
    ],
        "password" => "subhra123@"
    ];

    $headers = array("Authorization: Bearer $token"); 
    $requestUrl='http://hostapp.com/index.php/rest/V1/customers/25';


    $ch = curl_init();
    $ch = curl_init($requestUrl); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($customerData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . $token));   
    $result = curl_exec($ch); 

    $result = json_decode($result, 1);
    echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
```

Here I trying to update only the password using `entity_id` and getting the above error. I am using the postman and setting the `PUT` method there. Here I need to update those data for a customer.

Comment: Please update full code

Comment: may I know your magento 2 version?

Comment: you're passing array keys in wrong multidimensional order.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've not configured `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` correctly for **PUT** in your curl, replace

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($customerData));
```

with

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(json_encode($customerData)));
```

and it should work fine.